# Starting a program in another Desktop in Windows using Desktops Utility (Sysinternals)

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, selenium-webdriver, vbscript

Using the [Desktops](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc817881.aspx) program provided by Windows, it is possible to create multiple Desktops to execute programs. For example 4 desktops can be created named Desktop (1,2,3,4) etc.

I can switch between the desktops by hitting Alt+F1 or Alt+F2.

I would like to start a java selenium program in Desktop 2 using a batch file which I start from Desktop 1.

I have the following batch file -

```
cscript /nologo AltF2.vbs // To generate the ALT+F2 key press which 
                             switches my view from Desktop 1 to Desktop 2

java -jar selenium-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar // the selenium test which I want to run on Desktop 2
```

The contents of AltF2.vbs

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys "%{F2}" // Pressing ALT + F2
```

Currently my view changes to Desktop 2 after pressing "ALT + F2" but the java program executes in Desktop 1.

Is there a way in which I can make sure that the Java program runs on Desktop 2 instead of Desktop 1?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per their website Desktops does not have the capability to move windows from one desktop to another. All application windows are bound to the desktop on which they are started and therefore it is not possible to move windows across desktops.

I was able to satisfy my requirement by using the [Dexpot](http://www.dexpot.de/index.php?lang=en) software. With a help of hotkeys I was able to move windows from one Desktop to another.